# Move a body up and down

Tags: android, andengine

How can we move a sprite attached with a body up and down when click on the screen in And Engine game??? I have a sprite ball as a body and i want to move it up and down when user touch the screen..

```
ball=new PixelPerfectSprite(mCamera.getWidth()/10,mCamera.getHeight()/2-70, mResourceManager.ball,vbom);
  mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);//ball as a body
           final FixtureDef ballFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10f,0.5f,0);
           ballbody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld, ball, BodyType.DynamicBody, ballFixtureDef);
           ballbody.setUserData("ball");
 pc=new PhysicsConnector(ball, ballbody,true,false);

             registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(ballmove==true){
                        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(pc);
                        ballbody.setLinearVelocity(0,5f);

                    }
                     if(ball.getY()>=mCamera.getHeight()/2+70){


                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void reset() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

             });
  @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        ballmove=true;

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of options to get this done. Simplest one would be using Linear Velocity. So, the basic steps is:

- Register an Update Handler on that ball.
- Whenever it touches the ground, you should apply linear velocity on its body.
- Linear velocity lifts it up and after a while it touches the ground again (due to gravity).
- Step 2 (the process goes on)